# Non element-wise comparison of multi-dimensional arrays in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, comparison

This is probably a trivial problem, but I couldn't find a solution that doesn't involve a ton of `for`-loops.

I have a multi-dimensional array (an image, so `(h,w,3)`) and I want to find the indexes of the elements that have some rgb value.

Using the `==` operator, or the `np.where` function performs element-wise operations, so if my rgb tuple is `(0,0,255)` and I'm comparing it with `(0,0,0)` it will result in `(True, True, False)`, while the overall color is not the same and what I would want is just `False`. In other words, I'm looking for an operator that compares tuples and not the individual values.

Obviously, this would easily be done with a double for loop and the `.all()` operator, something like:

```
for i in range(xx.shape[0]):
    for j in range(xx.shape[1]):
        (xx[i,j,:] == (5,5,5)).all()
```

or this inside the loop:

```
np.array_equals(xx[i,j], (5,5,5))
```

But I was looking for a one-liner, something in the lines of `xx == (5,5,5)` but where the third axis is matched globally instead of element wise.

Comment: How about `(xx == (5,5,5)).all(-1)` that would use `broadcasting`?

Answer (score 0):

You could compare them element-wise and then use [`all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) along the third axis:

```
(xx == (5, 5, 5)).all(axis=2)
```

To get the indices you can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) around that:

```
np.where((xx == (5, 5, 5)).all(axis=2))
```

For example:

```
>>> xx = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [5, 5, 5]],
...                [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]])
>>> (xx == (5, 5, 5)).all(axis=2)
array([[False,  True],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)

>>> np.where((xx == (5, 5, 5)).all(axis=2))
(array([0], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64))
```

In case you don't feel comfortable using `all` and broadcasting that way you can also explicitly compare the values:

```
>>> (xx[..., 0] == 5) & (xx[..., 1] == 5) & (xx[..., 2] == 5)
array([[False,  True],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```